# How to filter backslash in Jmeter response body?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a request which will return a redirect URi, in Jmeter I get this response:

```
{
   "redirect_uri": "http:\/response.com/path
}
```

I want to filter it out, to change back into:

```
http://response.com/path
```

How can I achieve this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) it will automatically remove escape characters

[image]

Check out [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) for more information

There is also [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) available in [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) bundle which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) so for non-JSON response types you can substitute any character or combination of characters with another character or combination (including empty string) but it might not be the best idea in your case so just go for JSON Extractor